# page view count LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

i am still new to laravel and i want to implement visitors/view counter to my page, i looked everywhere and found a way but when i tried it it doesn't seem to work properly the views are always 0 .

this is the table where the views are stored :

```
Schema::create('views', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->morphs('viewable');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and this is the views Model :

```
class views extends Model
{
protected $table = 'views';
protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

and these are the functions i added to the model i want to count its visitors :

```
public function views()
{
    return $this->morphMany(
        \App\Models\views::class,
        'viewable'
    );
}

public function getViewsCount()
{
    return $this->views()->count();
}

public function getViewsCountSince($sinceDateTime)
{
    return $this->views()->where('created_at', '>', $sinceDateTime)->count();
}

public function getViewsCountUpto($uptoDateTime)
{
    return $this->views()->where('created_at', '<', $uptoDateTime)->count();
}
```

i called the function in my blade like this :

```
<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> {{$details->getViewsCount()}} Views
```

and i'm getting 0 views, i don't know if this is working or i am doing something wrong .. any ideas please !

Comment: Are there entries in your DB or why do you think that it is not working? How does your controller look like?

Comment: @Aless55 my controller has nothing to do with this ... do i need to add something in my controller ?

Comment: Where and how do you save the page views then?

Comment: @Aless55 as i said i am really new to laravel and that code i found didn't have anything about storing the views .. is there a way to store them please !

Comment: Laravel is based on the MVC architecture, so you will have to create a controller for example: PageViewController in this controller there should be a function called for example updateViewCount() which should update your database and return the new count. If you are completley new I recommend starting with the basics and not simply copy pasting code from someone else

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch

Comment: @Aless55 i know all about controllers and function, i added a "views" column in the "entreprise" table and made this function :
$details = entreprise::finde($id);
$details->increment(' views ');
the views increase every time i load the page but i need the unique views now

Answer (score 2):

The problem that I can see is the relationship.

The View model contains the viewable_id and viewable_type so the relationship should be a MorphTo.
And then for example if the Post model could have views then this would have the MorphMany relationship.

You are creating a one to many polymorphic relationship documented here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations.

Additionally, look into the withCount method, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models might be a better fit for what you want. So you can do something as follows:

```
Post::withCount('views');
```

Or if you need to filter the count based on when the view was done.

```
Post::withCount([
    'views' => function ($query) { 
        $query->where('created_at', >=, $someDate) 
    }
]);
```

And then you can access it like `$posts[0]->views_count`.

Edit:

I would also add to make sure that if you are adding data manually the viewable_type value would need to look like this `App\Models\View` or in laravel versions 7 or below the default location of the file would be `App\View`, but this depends on the location of your models.

Comment: You are right with your comments, but the real problem is that there is no request from the frontend to the backend to store the view.

Comment: Maybe, but this is not necessarily a fully finished project, I will sometimes do the backend code and then just manually input data into the database to make sure my index page is working first. The use of seeders means that you do not need the other crud pages to test the index page.

Edit: Also the fact that it is a View model would also imply that this would not need crud pages and would be something that is created when someone views a post for example. So creating a bunch of posts with views associated with them would probs be the best way to test this without implementing creating View

Comment: Yes you are totally correct with this approach and it is a helpful answer but if you read the first sentence of the question again I am pretty sure that the author expects some update behaviour that is obviously not happening. (and therefore I wanted to write my first comment)
Anyway, have a good one :)